# orchard cms module breakpoint

Tags: debugging, module, content-management-system, orchardcms, breakpoints

I want to debug a module and I set some breakpoints but when attach the orchard solution the breakpoints not hit, the breakpoint circles are not empty so the symbols are loaded.
I set breakpoints in display and both edit method of DateTimeFieldDriver and browse the page creation page.
What should i do?
I found that page creation do not uses the DateTimeFieldDriver , how its happen?

Comment: Where are you setting the breakpoint? Maybe that line of code isn't being executed? Breakpoints should work fine in an Orchard solution.

Comment: That was my misunderstanding of datetime field.